# datastax cqlsh alter table add column ,but can not see the column in hive , how?

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, datastax-enterprise

```
cqlsh:test> alter table example  add  t int;
then ， 
bash$dse hive 
hive> use test; desc example;
OK
k       int     from deserializer
v       string  from deserializer
```

The new column `t` is cannot be seen in hive.
dse version is 3.1.3.

What do need I do?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to drop any keyspaces or restart DSE or Hive, just drop the Hive table and let DSE recreate it by issuing a use command.

```
hive> desc ex;
OK
k   int from deserializer
v   string  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.054 seconds
hive> drop table ex;
OK
Time taken: 0.051 seconds
hive> desc ex;      
OK
Table ex does not exist      
Time taken: 0.051 seconds
hive> use foo;
OK
Time taken: 0.035 seconds
hive> desc ex;
OK
k   int from deserializer
t   int from deserializer
v   string  from deserializer
Time taken: 0.042 seconds
```

Edit: the same can be achieved by DROP TABLE followed by SHOW TABLES (i.e. SHOW TABLES instead of USE). As per the DataStax docs: http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/about_hive#handling-schema-changes

Answer (score 1):

Drop HiveMetaStore keyspace and MetaStore column family. Then restart DSE, restart HIVE, you should have a fresh start

Comment: I use beobal's method : drop table in hive ,then use db,It work ok .